# Problems using the Italian language pack in the EE control panel

Tags: control-panel, multi-language

I've got an EE 2.5.5 site and I'd like to be able to set the control panel language to Italian. I've followed the instructions on how to do this from the [user guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/languages.html).

I downloaded the [Italian language pack](https://github.com/EllisLab/EE-Language-Italian) from EllisLab's GitHub account, and I've uploaded the italian folder to system/expressionengine/language/**italian**. But when I set the language from english to italian, I get the following error:

```
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested language file: language/italian/core_lang.php
```

I have added an [issue](https://github.com/EllisLab/EE-Language-Italian/issues/1) on GitHub, but not sure if that is being monitored closely by EllisLab so thought I'd post here for help.

Is that language pack out of date (as there's not even a core_lang.php file within the repository), or do I need to be doing this in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're getting that error simply because the https://github.com/EllisLab/EE-Language-Italian pack is for EE 1.x versions.

Plus you can download this (though it's not 100% translated) at least it's a Version 2.1.3 https://bitbucket.org/age38dev/eecita/src/87fdcac9ce735f722f4cb182e40f51e42b92b043/2.1.3/EE/language?at=default

Comment: Damn, I didn't even consider/realise that, as I just assumed the language pack in EllisLab's own repository (and linked to from the EE2 docs) would surely be for the current major EE version. Thanks for pointing this out and the alternative EE2 download.